# How to add person in comment section in workitem programatically in c#

Tags: azure-devops

I want to add email id in the comment section, like using UI we use `@` symbol to add a person in the comment box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at some samples of this from our instance, the way this is stored within the comment text appears to be of the form:

`<a href="#" data-vss-mention="version:2.0,00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">@User Name</a>`

While I haven't tried this (related to policy around our instance and writing to it) I would expect it to work if you replace the zero-GUID with the GUID of the user (corresponding to the `id` property of their `IdentityRef`), and "User Name" with the display name (`displayName` from their `IdentityRef`).

The question currently doesn't indicate whether you're attempting to do this by directly using the REST services or through eg. the API provided by the Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client nuget package; the way you will retrieve the target user's `IdentityRef` and save the comment is going to depend on which approach is used.

Comment: I am using WorkItemTrackingHttpClient to create a work item.

Comment: I believe your comment will need to go in a `CommentCreate` instance, setting the `Text` property to the comment text (including the markup above) then pass it to `WorkItemTrackingHttpClient.AddComment`. I am yet to find a way to retrieve the user GUIDs directly, but you can see them where an `IdentityRef` is returned for other calls (pull requests, work items, etc).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I achieved this but the problem is from where I can get the Guid of the user.

Comment: https://blog.devmatter.com/get-a-list-of-vsts-users-with-apis/ use this blog to get the id field for user

Comment: You can also get UserIds by looking at the profile images in the Azure DevOps UI; the URLs to the images contain the associated UserIds.